# How can I change the font on this Marquee code? (HTML)

Tags: html

I'm new to coding in general but I've been looking all around for hours to find HTML for an infinite marquee text. I was able to finally get one by extracting it from the inspect element of https://invisiblefriends.io/ but when I paste it into my site, the font does not work the same. I want to be able to have the same grayed-out text and font they do but it defaults to this regular plain text instead. Is there any way to edit this code so it has the same functionality but I can change the font? Thank you in advance, I really appreciate it since I'm a marketer and I honestly have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to this

```html
</script><script src="/_next/static/Mah246YMdDVlGEfmee5QJ/_middlewareManifest.js" defer=""></script><style type="text/css">.marquee-container {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.marquee-container:hover div {
  animation-play-state: var(--pause-on-hover);
}
.marquee-container:active div {
  animation-play-state: var(--pause-on-click);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay::before, .overlay::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gradient-color));
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--gradient-width);
  z-index: 2;
}
.overlay::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.overlay::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.marquee {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  animation: scroll var(--duration) linear var(--delay) var(--iteration-count);
  animation-play-state: var(--play);
  animation-delay: var(--delay);
  animation-direction: var(--direction);
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}</style></head>
    <main class="font size=6" color=#f29913" face="Raleway, Helvetica"">
      <div class="text-outline-marquee bg-yellow-200 py-2 text-3xl text-yellow-200">
        <div class=" marquee-container" style="--pause-on-hover:running; --pause-on-click:running;">
          <div class="marquee" style="--play:running; --direction:reverse; --duration:224.145s; --delay:0s; --iteration-count:infinite;">
            <span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span></div><div class="marquee" style="--play:running; --direction:reverse; --duration:224.145s; --delay:0s; --iteration-count:infinite;"><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span></div></div></div><nav class="grid flex-none grid-cols-2 items-center p-5 lg:p-7"><div class="flex"></body><grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.marquee-container {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .marquee-container:hover div {
    animation-play-state: var(--pause-on-hover);
  }
  .marquee-container:active div {
    animation-play-state: var(--pause-on-click);
  }
  
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .overlay::before, .overlay::after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gradient-color));
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: var(--gradient-width);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .overlay::after {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  .overlay::before {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .marquee {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    animation: scroll var(--duration) linear var(--delay) var(--iteration-count);
    animation-play-state: var(--play);
    animation-delay: var(--delay);
    animation-direction: var(--direction);
  }
  @keyframes scroll {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<main class="font size=6" color=#f29913" face="Raleway, Helvetica"">
  <div class="text-outline-marquee bg-yellow-200 py-2 text-3xl text-yellow-200">
    <div class=" marquee-container" style="--pause-on-hover:running; --pause-on-click:running;">
      <div class="marquee" style="--play:running; --direction:reverse; --duration:224.145s; --delay:0s; --iteration-count:infinite;">
        <span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span></div><div class="marquee" style="--play:running; --direction:reverse; --duration:224.145s; --delay:0s; --iteration-count:infinite;"><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span><span class="uppercase">MINT PRICE: 1.5 SOL ·&nbsp;</span></div></div></div><nav class="grid flex-none grid-cols-2 items-center p-5 lg:p-7"><div class="flex"></body><grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration></html>

</body>
</html>
```